# automatically start a session at Windows 7 startup

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts

I would like to have the "guest" user automatically logged in at Windows 7 startup. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: [Windows 7 News & Tips](http://www.windows7news.com/2009/02/01/automatic-logon-into-windows-7/)

**Automatic Logon Into Windows 7:** Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. A command box should appear. Type `control userpasswords2` and hit the enter key. This should display the `User Accounts` screen in Windows 7. Select the user account ("guest" in your case) in the main table and uncheck the “Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer". A click on the `Apply` button will open the `Automatically Log On` window. Enter the password and confirm it to add the password to the system so that it does not need to be entered during logon.

[image]

Comment: Typing `control userpasswords2` did not work for me, but `netplwiz` did...